# About jQuery .each or other iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, iterator

How to iterate through table if it has this structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class = "fire"> ... </td>
    <td><input class = "water"> ... </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class = "fire"> ... </td>
    <td><input class = "water"> ... </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class = "fire"> ... </td>
    <td><input class = "water"> ... </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need at each iteration do this:

```
iterating:
     $("fire").val(newValue1); 
     $("water").val(newValue2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query for the class names:

```
 $(".fire").val(newValue1); 
 $(".water").val(newValue2);
```

Or:

```
$("table input.fire").each(function (i) {
  $(this).val("input " + i);
});

$("table input.water").each(function (i) {
  $(this).val("input " + i);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to iterate?

```
$('tr').each( function(){
    $(this).find('input.fire').val(newValue1);
    $(this).find('input.water').val(newValue2);
});
```

Comment: because i need always set different values on each <tr> where is fire and water classes

Answer (score 1):

If you need each iteration to have its own value, you could do this:

```
$("tr").each(function(i) {
    var newValue1 = "Some value"+i;
    var newValue2 = "Some other value"+i;
    $(this).find(".fire").val(newValue1);
    $(this).find(".water").val(newValue2);
});
```